# Damping constant (damped harmonic motion)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

For damped harmonic motion, the equation for the damping force is F=-bv where F is the damping force exerted on the object, v the velocity of the object and b the damping constant.

For an experiment, how would you keep the damping constant the same in every trial?

I know that the damping constant depends on size, shape and mass of an object, as well as the temperature of the liquid which the object is oscillating in.

Comment: It depends on the experiment, which is not described in your post - one can only guess that it happens in a liquid.

Comment: Lets say we have an object that is submerged into water and we cause it to start oscillating. The object is attached to a spring. The water has a damping constant.
Now, if we were to change the spring constant, but we let the same object (e.g. same size, shape and mass) oscillate in the same beaker of water (e.g. the same temperature), the damping constant should be the same as before, right?

Comment: There is also damping due to the string friction against the water.

Comment: ok, but if we neglect the string friction, the constant should stay the same? i am a bit confused about this topic

Comment: If the size and shape of the object remain the same, the friction coefficient should remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

The damping force relates to the amount of water that must be pushed out of the way so that the object can pass.  There are other factors such as friction along the sides of the object and decreased pressure behind the moving object.  Still, the effect can often be approximated as F=-bv.  Be sure the size, shape, and orientation do not change.  Be sure the object is symmetric, or the coefficient when the object moves up may be different from moving down.  This is very visible in a cone-shaped object.  Keep the maximum speed slow enough to avoid effects of turbulence.  Turbulence can change effects based on speed, thus making the damping force closer to a $v^2$ function.